# Как сделать ссылку на модель, которая ещё не объявлена?

Tags: python, django

Имеется модель:
models.py

```
class Country(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True) # Код страны
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) # Название страны

class Area(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True) # Код региона
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) # Название региона
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country) # Код страны
    capital = models.ForeignKey(City) # Код столицы региона

class City(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True) # Код города
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100) # Название города
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country) # Код страны
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area) # Код региона
```

Необходимо в **Area** (регионы) иметь ссылку на город (административный центр) в **City**.

Соответственно в трейсбеке получаю ошибку:

```
NameError: name 'City' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На момент инициализации ForeignKey(City) модель City еще не создана, поэтому либо перенесите её выше создания модели Area, либо пропишите название модели строчно:

```
capital = models.ForeignKey('City', related_name='capitals') # Код страны
```

Comment: City выше не перенесёшь, т.к. там ссылки на Country и Area.

Если сделать так:

    capital = models.ForeignKey('City')


то получаю трейсбек:

One or more models did not validate:
app.area: Reverse query name for field 'capital' clashes with field 'City.area'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'capital'.

Comment: Ну это уже другая проблема. Читайте свой трейсбэк внимательней, там же всё написано.  Поправил код в ответе, пробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо, почитал в доках, что такое related_name. Поправил. Теперь работает.

Появилась задача фильтрации городов при выборе админцентра, но это уже не проблема.